# Send and receive data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to web development, especially PHP, jQuery, AJAX...

I'm trying to make the user enter a name, then the index.html sends it to a php file, the php file saves it to a file of names and changes a div element with the id of status on the website.
I can't figure out the problem, the div element's inner HTML stays "processing..."

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    $.post("server.php", { username: $("#userName").val() }, function(data) {
    $("#status").html(data);
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
Username: <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text">  <br><br>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Check" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.php

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
        $data = $_POST['username'];
        echo 'You are now registered,' . $data;
        $fname = "save.text";

        $file = fopen($fname, 'a');
        fwrite($file, $data . "\n");
        fclose($file);
}
?>
```

I'm assuming my $.post syntax is wrong, but I don't really understand it.

Comment: What's your browser console say's?

Comment: You havent included the jQuery library, you should be seeing an error about your $.post line and that $ is not defined

Comment: I Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ajax_post @ (index):6 onclick @ (index):15                   (index): 6

Comment: Thanks, it worked :D. I didn't know I had to download a jquery javascript file and include it, but now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this I have executed this code and it worked for me.

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post(){
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    console.log($("#userName").val());
    $.post("server.php", { username: $("#userName").val() }, function(data) {
    $("#status").html(data);
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
Username: <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text">  <br><br>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Check" onclick="ajax_post()"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Server.php

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
        $data = $_POST['username'];
        echo 'You are now registered,' . $data;
        $fname = "save.text";

        $file = fopen($fname, 'a');
        fwrite($file, $data . "\n");
        fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: This also worked, except I suppose I don't have to download the jquery file. Thanks!